# Java Client and Server - Multiple Request

Tags: java, sockets

Currently I am trying to send files over Java sockets.  I can successfully send a request for a specific file and get the file back.  However, when I try to do it again without restarting the program I am unable to do so.

Here is my code:

Client

```
System.out.print("What file do you want? ");
    name = consoleIn.readLine();
    int bytesRead;

    if(!name.equals("!")) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        DataInputStream serverData = null;

        while(!name.equals("!")) {
            socketOut.println(name);
            socketOut.flush();

            InputStream is = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                is = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
            }

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not found. ");
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[4000];

            int count;

            while ((count = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            System.out.println("Here");
            bos.flush();


            System.out.print("What file do you want? ");
            name = consoleIn.readLine();
        }    
    }
```

Server

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted!");
            BufferedReader socketIn =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            //PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            String name;
            BufferedReader fileIn;
            String line;
            name = socketIn.readLine();
            System.out.println(name);

            while((!name.equals("!")) && (!name.equals("*"))) {

                File file = new File(rootDirectory, name);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[4000];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                int count;

                System.out.println("Sending: " + name);
                while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent");
                name = socketIn.readLine();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
```

I am not prompted to enter my second request.

Comment: Can u provide more or the whole code, please.

Comment: So where does it hang? Does the "Here" get printed? You need to also close your buffered stream in the client.

Comment: Sure thing.  Here are pastebins: http://pastebin.com/5ar6Vn7w and http://pastebin.com/Q2XLXwyM

Comment: @Kayaman I close it but the new prompt doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about the `FileServer:69` - you are accepting another user socket which blocks all the process.
Just remove this line from server and all should work.

What is more, I would suggest you to create a new thread for every accepted socket.

Comment: I have been looking at PasteBin just to be clear:) - there are some differences between code here and PasteBins.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look at that.  I tried to take out line 69 but it still hangs somewhere.  It won't let me enter a new file.